# for loop "index was out of range" c# webdriver

Tags: c#, loops, selenium-webdriver

I am getting "index out of range" from this loop. But I need to use new elements that loop founds, how do I do that? Please help to fix the problem

```
int linkCount = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("a[href]")).Count;
string[] links = new string[linkCount];

for (int i = 0; i < linkCount; i++)
{
    List<IWebElement> linksToClick = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("a[href]")).ToList();
    links[i] = linksToClick[i].GetAttribute("href");
}
```

Comment: Yes it is, you're trying to access list elements based off a count of a different list. It looks like links to click just needs moving outside of the for loop and then `links` needs a count of this list.

Comment: Don't create the `List<IWebElement>` in the loop on every iteration but once before the loop.

Comment: `linksToClick` does not have the same length as `links`. store `linksToClick` outside loop once and use it inside loop. if it must be inside loop for some reason then we are not your debugger.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary but when I store linksToClick outside the loop, I get "element not found in the cache"

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could refactor your code:

```
var linkElements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("a[href]")).ToList();
var links = new List<string>();

foreach (var elem in linkElements)
{
    links.Add(elem.GetAttribute("href"));
}
```

If that works, you could simplify the query:

```
var instantLinks = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("a[href]"))
                                .Select(e => e.GetAttribute("href"))
                                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your code to bypass the for loop:

```
string[] links = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("a[href]")).Select(l => l.GetAttribute("href")).ToArray();
```

This should also avoid the index out of range problem, and cut down the amount of code you have to write.

Answer (score 0):

```
int linkCount = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("a[href]")).Count;
List<string> links = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < linkCount; i++)
{
    List<IWebElement> linksToClick = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("a[href]")).ToList();
    if (linksToClick.Count < i)
        links.Add(linksToClick[i].GetAttribute("href"));
}
```

This might help with the out of range exception.
Doing this allows you to create a list of type: string without having to explicitly define the size of the list

Comment: I do feel that it would be better to define linksToClick once....
Surely that count will not change enough in the space that this loop runs...

Answer (score 0):

First of all i dont see a point in assigning linkstoclick values inside loop... And Reason for error must be that linksToClick list's length is more than that of linkCount.

Comment: I am trying to make test, that finds new elements when he opens another page, I though I could do it with a loop like this. Yes I know the reason why Im getting error, but I dont know how to make it work

Answer (score -1):

the first one gets all of your elements by tag name ...let's assume 5.

in the loop, your driver get's all the elements by css selector, and you might have a different number here. let's say 4.

then, you might be trying to set the fifth element in a four element array.
boom.

Easiest fix to debug:

```
int linkCount = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a")).Count;
string[] links = new string[linkCount];
// WRITE OUT HOM MANY links you have

for (int i = 0; i < linkCount; i++)
{
    List<IWebElement> linksToClick = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("a[href]")).ToList();
    // ASSERT THAT YOU HAVE THE SAME AMOUNT HERE
    If (links.Count != linksToClick.Count)
         // your logic here

    links[i] = linksToClick[i].GetAttribute("href");
}
```

Comment: but if I need to use all the new links loop founds, how do I make linkCount list not to fail the loop because of the static number it gets?

Comment: your issue is that the inner loop list is  smaller. define both the array and the list OUTSIDE of the loop to begin with. Then run from 1 to the smaller value, setting everything you can really.

Comment: Your two lists are different where OP's were the same. Miłosz Wieczorek's is the more efficient, more correct way to do this.