# how to make loop with a list work, that finds new elements? c# webdriver

Tags: c#, loops, selenium-webdriver

I want to create a loop that finds new elements every time, but I get exception "index out of range". When I store `linksToClick` out of the loop I get "element not found in the cache", so how to simplify my test that it works with list out of the loop?

```
    int linkCount = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("a[href]")).Count;
    string[] links = new string[linkCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < linkCount; i++)
        {
            List<IWebElement> linksToClick = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("a[href]")).ToList();
            links[i] = linksToClick[i].GetAttribute("href");
        }
```

Comment: is this a different question to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860391/for-loop-index-was-out-of-range-c-sharp-webdriver ?